# How to process single segment from fragmented mp4 container?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, rtmp, fmp4

I have fragmented mp4 that I stream. First the mp4 header and then individual segments that are each one GOP. It is h264 and aac encoded video that I am getting from RTMP server.

I would like to process these individual segments with ffmpeg(I doubt there are other tools available). Either adjust resolution or bitrate or even transcode to vp8/9 or avi1 if needed.

But it seems that ffmpeg cannot handle this because the segment has no header. So I wodner if there is a flag or set of flags for ffmpeg to be able to process these segments without the header? I could possibly just take the raw h264 and aac packets from the RTMP and not pack it into MP4 container beforehand, if that helps - would ffmpeg be able to process these?

Answer (score 0):

“So I wodner if there is a flag or set of flags for ffmpeg to be able to process these segments without the header? ‘

No. If it was possible, ffmpeg would just do it without they magic flag. The header contains information required for decoding.

You can pretend the header onto an individual  segment.

Comment: yeah but then i would have to extract the data out again which just brings unnecessary overhead. how about raw data as mentioned, can ffmpeg handle that?  ... or another library/software

Comment: Its is IMPOSSIBLE to decode a segment with the sequence headers, for ffmpeg or any other tool or command. Period. It contains information required to initialize the decoder such as resolution, profile, compression methods, color information, etc. Without the header, the decoder doesn't even know codec it is. RTMP has sequence headers sent at the start of the stream also, you just dont know that because you have tried it yet.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "extract the data again"? What do you mean by "extract"? and why "again" what as the first time you "extracted" it? headers are completely necessary, there is zero "unnecessary" overhead involved. Its all necessary.

Comment: you are right about the metadata in header. makes sense. as for extraction - i have fragmented mp4 container, so the header is just ftyp+moov and each segment is just moof+mdat where mdat contains the h264 video and aac audio packets, or in my case i split them into separate tracks for a/v so i have two separate segments. so if i would put header into each segment to process it via ffmpeg i would then have to extract that header out in order to be able to use that segment. though since i have the header in the first place it should be just a matter of cutting out the initial N bytes.